# What's the hotkey for selecting code enclosed by parenthesis in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

For example ,  I want to select from  24 to 33 with keyboard hotkey , How to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are looking for is Editor > Selection > Balance Delimiters. As for the "hot key", there are no fixed keyboard shortcut combinations in Xcode. The keyboard shortcut is whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a hotkey, but just double click on one of the `{` `}` brackets.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to matt's answer:

- unbind the ⌘+p since you will never print your code and bind it to the Balance Delimter.
- this also makes it easy to remember! ⌘+**P** for everything inside the **p**arenthesis